# How to access environment variable in post-build access for jira plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira

I installed `JIRA Plugin` for the jenkins. It add some action in `Post-build Action` menu. One of the action is **JIRA: Update relevant issues**.

When I try to access Environment Variable, it gives error.

```
WARNING: jira rest client get issue from jql search error. cause: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key '$MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key '$MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:289)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:262)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:91)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:69)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.get(DelegatingPromise.java:107)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraRestService.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(JiraRestService.java:177)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSession.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(JiraSession.java:136)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.selector.JqlIssueSelector.findIssueIds(JqlIssueSelector.java:49)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.Updater.perform(Updater.java:85)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater.perform(JiraIssueUpdater.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key '$MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:176)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:170)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:11)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:975)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:170)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:268)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:158)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:975)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:170)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

`$MY_ISSUE_ID` is valid environment variable, and I am able to access it on other section of the build.

I tried `issue=${XXXX}`, `issue=XXXX`, `issue="$XXXX"` etc... but all gives error.

After [answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/4855/9351) I tried `env. MY_ISSUE_ID` but it give same error.

```
WARNING: jira rest client get issue from jql search error. cause: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key 'env. MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key 'env. MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:289)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:262)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:91)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:69)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.get(DelegatingPromise.java:113)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraRestService.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(JiraRestService.java:177)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSession.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(JiraSession.java:132)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.selector.JqlIssueSelector.findIssueIds(JqlIssueSelector.java:46)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.Updater.perform(Updater.java:89)
    at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater.perform(JiraIssueUpdater.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuild.run(MultiJobBuild.java:76)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(400), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=400, errors={}, errorMessages=[The issue key 'env.MY_ISSUE_ID' for field 'issue' is invalid.]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:176)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:170)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:11)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:295)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:185)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:975)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:170)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:295)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:185)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:975)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:253)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList$RunnableExecutorPair.execute(ExecutionList.java:149)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:170)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$1$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable$1.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:197)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.runInContext(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:90)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient$ThreadLocalDelegateRunnable.run(SettableFuturePromiseHttpPromiseAsyncClient.java:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is the way to pass `environment variable` in **jql** for `post build action`.

When I gave `issue=MYPROJECT-1234`, it works fine. But, I want to set `MYPROJECT-1234` as environment variable.

Job **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobProject>
  <actions/>
  <description>&lt;!-- Managed by Jenkins Job Builder --&gt;</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <assignedNode>linux</assignedNode>
  <canRoam>false</canRoam>
  <properties>
    <com.coravy.hudson.plugins.github.GithubProjectProperty plugin="github">
      <projectUrl>https://myuser@mygithub.mydomain.com/myteam/myproject</projectUrl>
      <displayName/>
    </com.coravy.hudson.plugins.github.GithubProjectProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <name>origin</name>
        <refspec>+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*</refspec>
        <url>https://myuser@mygithub.mydomain.com/myteam/myproject.git</url>
        <credentialsId>github_username_with_token</credentialsId>
      </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>${sha1}</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <disableSubmodules>false</disableSubmodules>
    <recursiveSubmodules>false</recursiveSubmodules>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <remotePoll>false</remotePoll>
    <gitTool>Default</gitTool>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
    <reference/>
    <gitConfigName/>
    <gitConfigEmail/>
    <extensions/>
  </scm>
  <triggers class="vector">
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger>
      <spec>H/5 * * * *</spec>
      <adminlist/>
      <allowMembersOfWhitelistedOrgsAsAdmin>false</allowMembersOfWhitelistedOrgsAsAdmin>
      <whitelist/>
      <orgslist/>
      <whiteListLabels/>
      <blackListLabels/>
      <cron>H/5 * * * *</cron>
      <triggerPhrase>^\s*check\s+everything\s*$</triggerPhrase>
      <skipBuildPhrase/>
      <onlyTriggerPhrase>false</onlyTriggerPhrase>
      <useGitHubHooks>true</useGitHubHooks>
      <permitAll>true</permitAll>
      <autoCloseFailedPullRequests>false</autoCloseFailedPullRequests>
      <whiteListTargetBranches>
        <org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbBranch>
          <branch>staging</branch>
        </org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbBranch>
      </whiteListTargetBranches>
      <extensions>
        <org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.extensions.status.GhprbSimpleStatus>
          <commitStatusContext>pull request validation</commitStatusContext>
          <triggeredStatus>starting pull request validation...</triggeredStatus>
          <startedStatus>running pull request validation...</startedStatus>
          <completedStatus>
            <org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.extensions.comments.GhprbBuildResultMessage>
              <message>All is well.</message>
              <result>SUCCESS</result>
            </org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.extensions.comments.GhprbBuildResultMessage>
            <org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.extensions.comments.GhprbBuildResultMessage>
              <message>Something went wrong. Investigate!</message>
              <result>FAILURE</result>
            </org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.extensions.comments.GhprbBuildResultMessage>
          </completedStatus>
        </org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.extensions.status.GhprbSimpleStatus>
      </extensions>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger>
  </triggers>
  <builders>
    <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuilder>
      <phaseName>JIRA ID Validation</phaseName>
      <continuationCondition>SUCCESSFUL</continuationCondition>
      <executionType>PARALLEL</executionType>
      <phaseJobs>
        <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
          <jobName>cicd-myproject-prtest-jiraid</jobName>
          <currParams>true</currParams>
          <configs/>
          <abortAllJob>false</abortAllJob>
          <enableRetryStrategy>false</enableRetryStrategy>
        </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
      </phaseJobs>
    </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuilder>
    <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuilder>
      <phaseName>Tox Validation</phaseName>
      <continuationCondition>SUCCESSFUL</continuationCondition>
      <executionType>PARALLEL</executionType>
      <phaseJobs>
        <com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
          <jobName>cicd-myproject-prtest-unittest</jobName>
          <currParams>true</currParams>
          <configs/>
          <abortAllJob>false</abortAllJob>
          <enableRetryStrategy>false</enableRetryStrategy>
        </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.PhaseJobsConfig>
      </phaseJobs>
    </com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobBuilder>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>#!/bin/bash
echo "MY_ISSUE_ID=`echo ${ghprbPullLongDescription} | grep -e 'MY-[0-9]\+' -o`" &gt; MY_issue.property
</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
    <EnvInjectBuilder>
      <info>
        <propertiesFilePath>$WORKSPACE/MY_issue.property</propertiesFilePath>
      </info>
    </EnvInjectBuilder>
    <hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdateBuilder plugin="jira@3.0.0">
      <jqlSearch>issue=${MY_ISSUE_ID}</jqlSearch>
      <workflowActionName>Ready for Review</workflowActionName>
      <comment>[Unit Testing|${BUILD_URL}] Done</comment>
    </hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdateBuilder>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "'"${ghprbPullLink}"' is ready for review"}' <slackurl>
</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
  <publishers>
    <hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater plugin="jira@3.0.0">
      <issueSelector class="hudson.plugins.jira.selector.JqlIssueSelector">
        <jql>issue=${MY_ISSUE_ID}</jql>
      </issueSelector>
      <labels/>
    </hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater>
  </publishers>
  <buildWrappers>
    <hudson.plugins.ansicolor.AnsiColorBuildWrapper>
      <colorMapName>xterm</colorMapName>
    </hudson.plugins.ansicolor.AnsiColorBuildWrapper>
  </buildWrappers>
</com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.MultiJobProject>
```

Comment: hi! please attach your Jenkinsfile so we know exactly what you were running to access and use the env variable.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile added config file.

Answer (score 1):

You normally would access environment variables using the following syntax:

```
env.MY_ISSUE_ID
```

Typically you'll see the following in practice regarding envvars:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
    MY_ISSUE_ID = 'PROJECT-1234'
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        echo env.MY_ISSUE_ID
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
node{
  stage('Build') {
    withEnv(["MY_ISSUE_ID=PROJECT-1234"]) {
      echo env.MY_ISSUE_ID
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Casey, but I tried your answer, that not works with jira plugin.

Comment: Can you show us your pipeline?

Comment: means XML config ?

Comment: I added config file in the question.